# Is there any graph data structure implemented for C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, graph-theory

I tried to find a graph data structure to reuse in C# without any success. Of course, I can borrow from data structure books but I want it to be more commercially practical(?) Also I would appreciate if you can tell me what the best way of implementing a graph is. Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[QuickGraph](https://github.com/YaccConstructor/QuickGraph)

QuickGraph is a graph library for .NET that is inspired by Boost Graph Library.

QuickGraph provides generic directed/undirected graph datastructures and algorithms for .Net 2.0 and up. QuickGraph comes with algorithms such as depth first seach, breath first search, A* search, shortest path, k-shortest path, maximum flow, minimum spanning tree, least common ancestors, etc... QuickGraph supports MSAGL, GLEE, and Graphviz to render the graphs, serialization to GraphML, etc...

---

There are several ways to build graphs. The C++ Boost Graph Library (BGL) would be your best reference. It implements both adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix and edge-list graphs.
Look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) for details.

Comment: You expect some sorites marshalling of any kind to make it work for c# as it is a c# question, or ?...

Comment: There is another one, called `QuikGraph`, which forked `QuickGraph`, and is under active development.

Answer (score 42):

There is actually a fairly old article in MSDN that covers graph creation in C#, [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx#datastructures20_5_topic3). Despite its age, it still addresses your question as long as you don't mind creating your own graph class(es).

Comment: @Tae-SungShin Most of the basic concepts and algorithms about the graph theory is older than at least 20 years. So the article is still valid and an up-to-date resource IMHO.

Comment: To keep things interesting, Microsoft keeps shuffling stuff around. A modern link that will take you directly to the above article is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379574(v=vs.80)#datastructures20_5_topic3

Answer (score 8):

Under active development, there is https://www.nuget.org/packages/QuikGraph You can view source code on GitHub https://github.com/KeRNeLith/QuikGraph and also read the wiki https://github.com/KeRNeLith/QuikGraph/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on graph theory library for 3 years till now.

It is pretty comprehensive, have a lot of algorithms built in.

I decided to create it because Quick graph was dead and didn't implement features I needed.

https://github.com/Kemsekov/GraphSharp