# Linq query isn't returning any values while it should

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have the following table:

```
Track
----------------------
FromStop  ToStop
2         3
3         5
3         6
3         7
3         8
5         7
5         8
6         8
7         8
8         9
```

Each number represents a station and one entry in this table represents a line of tracks between the two stations.

I wrote the following code to determine what other stations are between 2 stations:

```
public List<Stop> GetClosestConnectingStops(int fromStopId, int toStopId)
{
    using (TrainBlocksEntities objContext = new TrainBlocksEntities())
    {
        List<Track> trackList;

        //2 stops
        var x = from n in objContext.Tracks
                where (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n.ToStop == toStopId) 
                //1 switches
                || (n.FromStop == toStopId && n.ToStop == fromStopId)
                select n;
        trackList = x.ToList<Track>();
        if (trackList.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Stop> stops = new List<Stop>();
            if(trackList[0].Stop.Id == fromStopId){
                stops.Add(trackList[0].Stop);
                stops.Add(trackList[0].Stop1);
            }else{
                stops.Add(trackList[0].Stop1);
                stops.Add(trackList[0].Stop);
            }
            return stops;
        }

        //3 stops
        var y = from n in objContext.Tracks
                from n2 in objContext.Tracks
                where (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n.ToStop == n2.FromStop && n2.ToStop == toStopId)
                //2 switches
                || (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n.ToStop == n2.ToStop && n2.FromStop == toStopId)
                //1 switch
                || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n.FromStop == n2.FromStop && n2.ToStop == toStopId)
                    //2 switches
                || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n.FromStop == n2.ToStop && n2.FromStop == toStopId)
                select new StopConcat
                {
                    DepartureStop = n.Stop,
                    Intermediate1 = n2.Stop,
                    ArrivalStop = n2.Stop1
                };
        List<StopConcat> options = y.ToList<StopConcat>();
        if (options.Count > 0)
        {
            Stop[] stops = {options[0].DepartureStop, options[0].Intermediate1, options[0].ArrivalStop};
            return stops.ToList<Stop>();
        }

        //4 stops <---- THIS DOESNT WORK
        var z =
            from n in objContext.Tracks
            from n2 in objContext.Tracks
            from n3 in objContext.Tracks
            where 
               (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n2.FromStop == n.ToStop && n3.FromStop == n2.ToStop && n3.ToStop == toStopId)
            //3 switches
            || (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n2.FromStop == n.ToStop && n3.ToStop == n2.ToStop && n3.FromStop == toStopId)
            //2 switches
            || (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n2.ToStop == n.ToStop && n3.FromStop == n2.FromStop && n3.ToStop == toStopId)
                //3 switches
            || (n.FromStop == fromStopId && n2.ToStop == n.ToStop && n3.ToStop == n2.FromStop && n3.FromStop == toStopId)
            //1 switch
            || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n2.FromStop == n.FromStop && n3.FromStop == n2.ToStop && n3.ToStop == toStopId)
                //3 switches
            || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n2.FromStop == n.FromStop && n3.ToStop == n2.ToStop && n3.FromStop == toStopId)
                //2 switches
            || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n2.ToStop == n.FromStop && n3.FromStop == n2.FromStop && n3.ToStop == toStopId)
                    //3 switches
            || (n.ToStop == fromStopId && n2.ToStop == n.FromStop && n3.ToStop == n2.FromStop && n3.FromStop == toStopId)
            select new StopConcat
            {
                DepartureStop = n.Stop,
                Intermediate1 = n.Stop1,
                Intermediate2= n3.Stop,
                ArrivalStop = n3.Stop1
            };
        options = z.ToList<StopConcat>();
        if (trackList.Count > 0)
        {
            StopConcat firstOption = options[0];
            ArrayList stops = new ArrayList();
            if(firstOption.DepartureStop.Id == fromStopId){
                stops.Add(firstOption.DepartureStop);
                stops.Add(firstOption.Intermediate1);
            }
            else
            {
                stops.Add(firstOption.Intermediate1);
                stops.Add(firstOption.DepartureStop);
            }
            if (firstOption.ArrivalStop.Id == toStopId)
            {
                stops.Add(firstOption.Intermediate2);
                stops.Add(firstOption.ArrivalStop);
            }
            else
            {
                stops.Add(firstOption.ArrivalStop);
                stops.Add(firstOption.Intermediate2);
            }

            return stops.Cast<Stop>().ToList();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Example of the code:

```
 - GetClosestConnectingStops(2,5) -> {2,3,5}
 - GetClosestConnectingStops(3,5) -> {3,5}
```

The above examples work, but when I try to connect 2 stations with 2 other stations in between, the function returns null.

```
Expected result:
 - GetClosestConnectingStops(2,9) -> {2,3,8,9}
Actual result
 - GetClosestConnectingStops(2,9) -> null
```

Something is wrong with my third Linq-query but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: What you have here is path detection in a graph.  Assuming your graph isn't too large like the example I would suggest creating a graph data structure, loading the data from you DB into it and then using known algorithms for traversing graphs, like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for finding the shortest path.

Comment: I've thought about using Dijkstra's algorithm, but I've never used it before so I'm not sure how to incorporate it. I'm also fairly new at Linq, so any examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532882/is-there-any-graph-data-structure-implemented-for-c-sharp).  There's an answer that mentions a library that might handle all the work for you.

Comment: Your implementation seems to boil down to analysis of special cases. You would get more reliable results easier if you use some common "shortest path" algorithm, e.g. [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/pathfinding)